# With the command button in VBA it has to calculate and filter out values and then change them

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

for a school work i have to program a VBA that has the function to go throw the whole column and filter out all the outstanding values and change them. The other function has to be to create a new work sheet or more of them and sort on them all of the information. like in one work sheet it has to saporate the information on monthly base. i tried a few things bot i dont even get the part working to fillter the columns

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: I tried to go step bi step. first i was trying to code a part that would calculate the average of the column but al the time it gives a error massage. after that i wanted to do an if statement that would analise the column and would change every number that's not the average

Comment: This is not a code writing service\website. Please show example data, any code and formulas used and error messages received. It is also helpful to provide examples of expected results.